# How to fix Empty data give error Get Property

Tags: laravel

I have a Function to showing a single data . but if this data empty its having error. I using first because just want to

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

its my Controller

```
  public function PDF_profile(Request $request,$id){
    $users = User::findOrFail($id);
    $pns   = Data_pns::where('user_id',$id)->first();
    $pendidikan = Data_riwayat_pendidikan::where('user_id',$id)->latest()->first();;
    $r_kgb = DB::table('data_riwayat_kgb')->latest()->first();


    $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.pdf_profile',
    ['users' => $users,
    'pendidikan'=>$pendidikan,
    'r_kgb'=>$r_kgb,
    'pns'  => $pns,


    ]);
    // dd($pns);
     return $pdf->stream('Profile.pdf')->header('Content-Type','application/pdf'); 

}
```

my View

```
    <table align="left"  border=""  >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> <b>Riwayat Pendidikan </b></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>  
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td> <b>Tingkat Pendidikan </b></td>

      <td>:
        {{ $pendidikan->jenjang}}
      </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <b> Tempat Pendidikan</b></td>
      <td>:{{$pendidikan->nama_tempat}}</td>


    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td><b>Konsentrasi/Jurusan</b></td>
      <td>:{{ $pendidikan->jurusan}}</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td><b>Tahun Lulus</b></td>
      <td>:{{$pendidikan->lulus_tahun}}</td>
    </tr> 

  </tbody>
</table>
```

its just part on my view .

and this line is mentioned error .

```
<td>:
    <?php echo e($pendidikan->jenjang); ?>

  </td>
```

but if this data is inputed or not empty its not having error . how to solved it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first check if the object is not `null` as `first()` returns `null` hence the error, so do this instead:

```
<td>:
    @if($pendidikan)
        {{$pendidikan->nama_tempat}}
    @endif
</td>
```

You can also replace this: `->latest()->first()` with just calling `last()`.

Comment: Wait i will trying it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optional() helper method

```
{{ optional($pendidikan)->nama_tempat}}
```

or short form @

```
{{ @$pendidikan->nama_tempat}}
```